# Postgres order by 1st event in group of events

Tags: sql, postgresql

I do a lot of looking at user behavior and want an easy way to order by the first event in a group of events per user. i.e.

```
User1 | Event1
User1 | Event2
User1 | Event3
User2 | Event1
User2 | Event2
User2 | Event3
```

Where Event1 for User1 is earlier than Event1 for User2.

I know I could make a table with each users' first event and then join it, but I feel like there is a simpler way I am just not seeing. Any ideas?

Comment: Without a date, how do you know that U1E1 is before U2E1?

Comment: Postgres version, table definition, fiddle with sample rows; define your desired sort order clearly and unambiguously, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `first_value` window function, but in my experience it would probably be slower than the join to the derived table.

```
select userid, event from foo order by first_value(event) over (partition by userid order by something)
```

In case you didn't know, you can do the join to a dynamically defined aggregate table, it doesn't have to be a permanent table.

It would be easier to offer example queries if your example data had included things like column names, or even all the necessary example columns.

Comment: BEAUTIFUL! Thanks! `first_value` is something I haven't used before and I like it a lot partly because I feel like someone reading it for the first time would still understand what it's doing.
A note to anyone who stumbles upon this in the future, I had to add `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` after the `order by something` for it to work on redshift.

Answer (score 1):

Could be as simple as this if I understand correctly:

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table_name
ORDER BY user_field, event_field;
```

Or try the ORDER BY in reversed if you want all the Event 1s first

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table_name
ORDER BY event_field, user_field;
```

Comment: The first example does put all of the events in order with their users, however if my first ever user was "Zed" and my latest user was "Abe" it would still list Abe's events before Zed's. Whereas I want each users events together starting with each users' earliest event.

The second answer would sort all of the events first, so if Abe and Zed both had an event on `2022-09-08 00:00` then those events would be next to each other despite being from different users.